# Handlebar iterate/loop through json with subarray

Tags: php, javascript, json, loops, handlebars.js

I trying to loop trough the following JSON with HandleBars;

```
{
"IndexValues": {
    "inv": {
        "1": {
            "live": {
                "INV": "1",
                "ITP": 719.166962
            },
            "day": 14,
            "week": 85,
            "month": 232
        },
        "2": {
            "live": {
                "INV": "2",
                "ITP": 719.166962
            },
            "day": 14,
            "week": 93,
            "month": 237
        },
        "dayK": 28,
        "week": 178,
        "montk": 469
    }
}
}
```

The above JSON i try to loop with the following HandleBar:

```
{{#data.IndexValues.inv}}
    <!-- the following is showing data, but is not dynamic -->
    {{this.1.live.INV}}
    <br>
    {{this.2.live.INV}}

    <!-- the following doenst work -->
    {{#this}}
        {{this.live.INV}}
    {{/this}}

    <!-- the following is showing data, but is not dynamic -->
    {{#this}}
        {{this.1.live.INV}}
    {{/this}}
{{/data.IndexValues.inv}}
```

The thing is that "inv" is dynamic and could be in the range of 1-256

Comment: Just a thought, but why loop through it with handlebars?  Why not make a template for one element and then loop through your json object and render the template per element?

Comment: What do you mean? That i split the json-request in multiple request and render these request by multiple handlebars? If so, when i have 100 inv "objects" it will slow the page terribly down.

Comment: No, and its not my plan to test it. its going to be a production website and if 10 people request the page, the server get 10x100=1000 request a second. That not a option.

Comment: You don't have to do an individual request for each time you render the template.  You can grab the whole object at once and then break it down.  Second of all, IndexValues.inv can be an array, making it easy to iterate through it and render your template for each inv in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars loop only works for array elements  ( the [ ] notation), not object fields (the { } notation).  Your sample JSON does not have an array in it.  Either you (a) change your JSON to have a list or (b) create a new array then pass that on to your Handlebars template.

(a) change JSON (add "inv.data" list)

```
{
"IndexValues": {
    "inv": {
        data: [{
            "id" : 1,
            "live": {
                "INV": "1",
                "ITP": 719.166962
            },
            "day": 14,
            "week": 85,
            "month": 232
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "live": {
                "INV": "2",
                "ITP": 719.166962
            },
            "day": 14,
            "week": 93,
            "month": 237
        }],
        "dayK": 28,
        "week": 178,
        "montk": 469
    }
}
}
```

You Handlebar template would then be:

```
{{#data.IndexValues.inv.data}}
    ...
{{/#data.IndexValues.inv.data}}
```